# Java NIO TCP Server connection handling issue

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, nio

I read an [article](http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/) and 
wrote a `TCP` server that handles approximately 10000 connections and I also wrote a program that opens 10000 client connections for testing the server program. When I communicate with them using loop back address on the same PC, the server sometimes can't handle all the connections. So the client sends a frame but the server can't send (program specific) acknowledge frame(not tcp ack). But If I run this simulation with approximatily 1000 connecttions,everything works fine.

Here is my connection handler code:

```
    public void run() {
    while (true) {
        try {
            synchronized (this.pendingChanges) {
                Iterator changes = this.pendingChanges.iterator();
                while (changes.hasNext()) {
                    ChangeRequest changeRequest = (ChangeRequest) changes.next();
                    if (changeRequest.socket.isOpen() == true) {
                        SelectionKey key = changeRequest.socket.keyFor(this.selector);
                        key.interestOps(changeRequest.ops);
                    }
                }
                this.pendingChanges.clear();
            }
            this.selector.select();
            Iterator selectedKeys = this.selector.selectedKeys().iterator();
            while (selectedKeys.hasNext()) {
                SelectionKey key = (SelectionKey) selectedKeys.next();
                selectedKeys.remove();
                if (!key.isValid()) {
                    continue;
                }
                if (key.isAcceptable()) {
                    this.accept(key);
                } else if (key.isValid() && key.isReadable()) {
                    this.read(key);
                } else if (key.isValid() && key.isWritable()) {
                    this.write(key);
                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(CancelledKeyException ce){
            //System.out.println("Key zaten cancel edilmis");
        }
    }
}
private void read(SelectionKey key) throws IOException {
    SocketChannel socketChannel = (SocketChannel) key.channel();
    if (socketChannel.isOpen() == true) {
        this.readBuffer.clear();
        int numRead;
        try {
            numRead = socketChannel.read(this.readBuffer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (socketChannel.isOpen()) {
                socketChannel.close();
                queueObject.socket = socketChannel;
                queueObject.isAlive = false;
                this.worker.addSocketToQueue(queueObject);
            }
            if (socketChannel.isRegistered()) {
                key.cancel();
            }
            //this.worker.deleteConnection(socketChannel);
            return;
        }
        if (numRead == -1) {
            if (socketChannel.isOpen()) {
                socketChannel.close();
                queueObject.socket = socketChannel;
                queueObject.isAlive = false;
                this.worker.addSocketToQueue(queueObject);
            }
            if (socketChannel.isRegistered()) {
                key.cancel();
            }
            // System.out.println("Socket kapatildi");
            // this.worker.deleteConnection(socketChannel);
            return;
        }
        queueObject.data = readBuffer.array();
        queueObject.size = numRead;
        queueObject.socket = socketChannel;
        queueObject.isAlive = true;
        this.worker.addSocketToQueue(queueObject);
    }
}
```

And here is my worker thread code:

```
public class Worker implements Runnable, ConnectionManager.ConnectionCallbacks {

private LinkedList<QueueObject> queue = new LinkedList<>();
private HashMap<SocketChannel, ConnectionManager> connections = new HashMap<>();
private DatabaseWorker databaseWorker;
private int connectionCount = 0;
NioServer server;
Thread t;
int counter = 0;
private int actPackCount = 0;

public Worker(NioServer server) {
    this.server = server;
    t = new Thread(this);
    t.setPriority(Thread.NORM_PRIORITY+1);
    t.start();
    databaseWorker = new DatabaseWorker();
}

public void addSocketToQueue(QueueObject queueObject) {

    byte[] datacopy = new byte[queueObject.size];
    System.arraycopy(queueObject.data, 0, datacopy, 0, queueObject.size);
    synchronized (queue) {
        queue.add(new QueueObject(queueObject.socket, datacopy, queueObject.size, queueObject.isAlive));
        queue.notify();
    }
}

public void createConnection(SocketChannel socket) {

   // synchronized (this.connections) {
        connectionCount++;
        ConnectionManager connectionManager = new ConnectionManager(this, socket, databaseWorker);
        this.connections.put(socket, connectionManager);
        try(BufferedWriter bw=new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("/home/yusuf/NetBeansProjects/YososServer/ConnectionCreateLog",true))){
            bw.write("Connection Create:"+connectionCount);
            bw.newLine();
        }catch(IOException e){

        }
   // }
}

public void deleteConnection(SocketChannel socket) {
    synchronized (this.connections) {
        this.connections.remove(socket);
    }
}

@Override
public void run() {
    QueueObject queueObject;
    ConnectionManager connectionManager;
    while (true) {
        synchronized (queue) {
            while (queue.isEmpty()) {
                try {
                    queue.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {

                }
            }
            queueObject = queue.remove();
        }
        synchronized (this.connections) {

            connectionManager = this.connections.get(queueObject.socket);
        }
        if (connectionManager != null) {
            connectionManager.addData(queueObject);
            if (queueObject.isAlive = false) {
                deleteConnection(queueObject.socket);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The `ConnectionManager` class will parse the frame and return to the worker class with callback functions. Each `ConnectionManager` class instance creates a timer using `ScheduledExecuterService` for timeouts.

What is the problem in my code?
Thanks for your intereset.

Comment: Have you profiled your code?

Comment: Yes,I am using it in non-blocking mode

Comment: 'I am using it in non-blocking mode' isn't an answer to 'have you profiled your code'. You don't need all this queuing. It's an urban myth deriving ultimately from a poor quality article by someone in Amazon South Africa. You only need `Selector.wakeup()` in the cases where you are registering or cancelling channels from another thread, and why you would be doing that is a mystery in the first place.

Comment: don't write your own nio server, use  a framework such as [netty](http://netty.io/). Also don't abuse a `LinkedList` as queue when there are actual queues.

Comment: @EJP you are rigtht, I derived my code from http://rox-xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/niotut/ address.
But how can i parse and handle all frames without queue